# How will be the query performance on year column vs date range column

Tags: mysql, sql-server, oracle, postgresql, query-performance

I have a Spring boot application. There is a table (say invoices) having `financial_year` column, `invoice_date` column and other columns. I have to make a `SELECT` query on this table to fetch all the records for the given financial year and there would be other where conditions also.

My question is which one of these two queries have better performance or is there any other way to achieve the same?

*startDate* and *endDate* will be the start date of the financial year and end date of the financial year respectively. *financialYear* will be of the form '2020_2021'. *invoiceDate* is only the date part of datetime.

1. `SELECT * FROM invoices WHERE invoice_date BETWEEN :startDate AND :endDate`
2. `SELECT * FROM invoices WHERE financial_year = :financialYear`

My application is quite different. It has routing datasource and it supports MSSQL, MySQL, PostgreSQL and Oracle based on our users in different plaforms having databases mentioned. So I have to consider performance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both queries looks OK. One thing that you need to consider is using proper indexing on tables. If your data is mainly filtered by financial_year and if the data has more than lets say several thousands of rows, you need to consider to add index for financial_Year. Same thing applies to invoice_date as well.

Always use explain plans to trace performance of your queries. And keep in mind that, good understanding on explain plans will have great benefit on your journey.

Comment: Great. Also thanks for the additional information ("explain")

Comment: Invoice_date will have much more different values and if it contains date and time it will be bigger than 9 characters, that means that index on it will be bigger. That's not so easy and require deeper analysis

Comment: invoice_date is only date

Answer (score 1):

[MySQL-centric answer]

Short answer:   The two queries you propose have identical performance.  (This assumes `INDEX(invoice_date)` or `INDEX(financial_year)` as appropriate.)

Long answer:

But...

Once you leave those limited `WHERE` clauses, performance is *likely* to vary:

```
WHERE x > 5 AND financial_year = :financialYear
```

`INDEX(financial_year, x)` is efficient, but the start-enddate version cannot be made efficient.

`GROUP BY` and/or `ORDER BY` would necessitate rethinking the index and might not be efficient.

With newer versions of MySQL, you have a "generated" column that is also indexed.  This is relatively cheap and allows you to optimize either way, without the risk of the two columns getting out of sync.

Good luck on handling multiple version of SQL.  There tend to be incompatible differences and/or missing features.

MySQL does not have bitmapped indexing, and its `PARTITIONing` is generally useless for performance.

`financial_year` could be an `ENUM` (1 byte) or a `YEAR` (2 bytes).

Answer (score 0):

In case of huge cardinality it's usually better to considere partitioning or bitmap indexes. Both of them have own pros and cons and require much deeper analysis than just 1 query.

Comment: can you provide documentation for bitmap indexing specifically om date and time column?

Comment: https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/sharma-indexes.html

Comment: from the documentation "Conventional wisdom hulds that bitmap indexes are most appropriate for columns having low distinct values". my first sight says do not use bitmap index for date, datetime and timestamp. I am trying to find answer for "why do I need to use bitmap index for these columns?"

Comment: I'm talking about financial year

Comment: In case of date only without time, that can be considered too

Comment: So, what am I supposed to do now? I have added index for both the columns.